# Cannot find a device attached to network

Tags: router, mac-address, draytek

My work has a wireless alarm system installed, and we recently got a wireless camera to add to it (made by the same company, it simply plug-n-plays).

The alarm system uses a small router like device to hook everything up, and that "bridge" device it plugged into the proper router.

I can see the IP address of the bridge device, but it is not made to access in anyway, this is OK.

The camera we got links up wireless-ly, and despite knowing the MAC address (it was on the back of the camera) I cannot seem to find it on the router.

I have noticed a random device on the network, which when inspected with FING on my Android phone, has RTSP protocol available, as well as FTP and a HTTP port, leading me to believe this is the camera, but the MAC address is different.

So, is it possible for the camera to "hide" itself on the network? Or is this mystery device likely it, and somehow has 2 MAC addresses for some reason?

Comment: Does the camera also have an ethernet port?  Both the wireless adapter and any ethernet adapter would have their own MAC addresses.

Comment: It does! So the MAC address on the camera must be the Ethernet adapter. Meaning the mystery device is the cameras WiFi adapter?! OK, so now how to I figure out how ot access it> It is running mini_httpd but asks for a username and password. There is also an FTP port available, but I imagine that is also protected some how. I have also tried accessing the RTSP port via rtsp://<ip-address>:554 but no luck (using VLC)

Comment: That's probably it.  Most likely the camera has a default username/password combo that can be found either in it's documentation or on the Internet.

Comment: I've tried looking, but i can't find anything :(

Comment: so I found out the camera is made by StarVedia, despite being sold by a totally different company. I downloaded software from StarVedia for their camera range, and managed to connect ot the camera, using an ID # and password code I managed to gather from the shockingly bad web app. I need to try and figure out how it is connecting and see if I can get it to stream inside a modern browser?

Comment: I don't have any experience with those.  Good luck!